# Enable bundling and minification in debug mode in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I can't believe I cannot find other questions about this, but: how does one *enable* bundling in debug mode? I know how it is enabled for release mode, but in debug mode I cannot find a way to enable the bundling.

Is this even possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can enable this by adding

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

in your RegisterBundles method (BundleConfig class in the App_Start folder).

check http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification for more info

You could also change your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
</system.web>
```

But this would disable debug mode entirely so I would recommend the first option.

Finally, to get the best of both worlds, use the #if compiler directive like this:

```
#if DEBUG
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

Comment: I would take this a step further, and add a custom config section to your web.config (or at a minimum, an AppSetting entry.)  That way, you can selectively enable/disable optimizations without having to do a rebuild.

Comment: or use `#if DEBUG` & `#if !DEBUG` precompiler statements

Comment: Also bear in mind that this overrides the `debug="true"` config, so optimisations are always enabled or disabled if you hardcode this value

Comment: Or use "verbose" MVC like `if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) { BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false; } else { BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; }`

Comment: if you like the web config option you can also setup multiple web configs per configuration so debug web config would be true and release would be false

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations/_static/image1.png

Comment: VS2019 - I've set BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; in global.asax file, but still getting error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' where trying to open a page with bundle in debug mode.

Comment: This enables bundling, not minification.

Answer (score 13):

add  `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` in `Application_Start()` method of `Global.asax` file

Answer (score -3):

In Global.asax add `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);`

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles); // add this
        }
```

Answer (score -5):

The [official MS site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) states while Debugging it's not possible to enable it. I think the reason is, that it's easier to debug while it's disabled. If you want to test the Impact on your application you have to set `<compilation debug="true" />` in the Web.config

@Hebe: To Quote the MS page

> It's easy to debug your JavaScript in a development environment (where the  compilation Element in the Web.config file is set to debug="true" ) because the JavaScript files are not bundled or minified.

Comment: In my case, I merely wanted to debug the backend C# code, and due to the way our application is set up, we need bundling to work for all the stylesheets and scripts to load properly.

Comment: @Ennosuke - While it may be easier to debug, sometimes there's Javascript bugs caused by the minification process that require you to be able to run the minified scripts locally.