# How to load specific file script and css in bundles C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC solution and have a lot of JS and CSS for all of website, when the page loading, all of JS and CSS is also loading, but some of page only need some of specific JS or CSS in bundles.
Ex:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js",
            "~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js",
            "~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.minicolors.js",
            "~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.fontselector.js"));
```

In page A I render script like that:

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
      <%: Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery") %>
 </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

But in page B, I want only load jquery-1.9.1.js, not load to all js in bundles.
So my question is how to load specific file js in page B.

Comment: Add a new script bundle that _only_ includes _jquery-1.9.1.js_, and load only that script bundle. Then I suggest that you check if there is actually any performance difference. It might be better to just include them all for simplicity because excluding the other three files makes very little difference performance wise, and selectively including css and js on different pages can make debugging a nightmare. Also, consider forcing bundling so that you can debug it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030905/enable-bundling-and-minification-in-debug-mode-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many bundles as you need:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/jquery").Include(
        "~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js",
        "~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js",
        "~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.minicolors.js",
        "~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.fontselector.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/justjquery").Include("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"));
```

And in your view:

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
      <%: Scripts.Render("~/scripts/justjquery") %>
 </asp:PlaceHolder>
```