# ASP.NET MVC Bundles for css are blank with OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, bundling-and-minification

We have recently moved our `ASP.NET 5.2.3` application to `OWIN 3.0.1` and are having bundling issues.  The `*.js` is bundling appropriately, but the `*.css` bundles are coming out blank.

Where can I look for more details from the bundling output to figure out what's happening?

### Code structure

**Login.cshtml**

```
<head>
...
    @Html.RenderStyles("~/static/css/LoginPage")
...
</head>
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Foo.bar.Web.Bootstrapper {
  public class BundleConfig {
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
      bundles.UseCdn = true; //enable CDN support

      bundles
       .Add(new StyleBundle("~/static/css/LoginPage")
       .Include(
         "~/Static/css/login.css", 
         "~/Static/css/chosen.css")
       );
    }
  } 
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Foo.Bar.Web.Bootstrapper {
    public class Startup {
        private IContainer container;
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            //Commenting/Uncommenting this makes no difference.
            //BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: Firstly, don't let your bundle name collide with _real_ folders. In other words change your bundle name to something like `~/bundle/static/css/LoginPage` in your BundleConfig.cs definition and in your Login.cshtml. Bundling really is a pain

Comment: Also can you confirm there are no 404 errors in your network tab. How do you know the CSS is blank? Are you using F12 tools to look at it?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I am using chrome developer tools to inspect the bundle. I will try changing the path, as well as double-checking the network tab.

Comment: Good luck, It's really painful. Also be aware that when you're in debug mode it turns off bundling automatically. Which is what  I found out when my site worked perfectly then when I published it it failed completely because bundling was incorrect. See her on how to force bundling on and off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030905/enable-bundling-and-minification-in-debug-mode-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: changing the path to `~/bundles/css/LoginPage` worked!  Please respond as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to to ensure is that your bundle name doesn't collide with real folders.

In other words change your bundle name to something like `~/bundle/static/css/LoginPage`

in both your `BundleConfig.cs` definition and in your `Login.cshtml`

Comment: Thanks!  Doing this populated the style bundles, but then I ran into many 404s because of relative paths in the stylesheets.  >_<.  That made me realize my underlying problem wasn't in the bundling, though, but rather some middleware that was reading routes.  The style bundles were slipping through the defined routes, and then the middleware was throwing an exception.  Thanks for helping me think through this, though, and your answer is still the *right* one.  Cheers!

Comment: Oh good! I actually still have a problem myself with relative paths in bootstrap - I can't use glyphicons.